# Set cookie to only play animation once (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have an animation that I am running using jQuery.  I am assuming a good way to only play this animation once for the visitor is by setting a cookie.  I basically need it to say you've been here before so set all the IDs listed to opacity:1 Is there an ultra simple solution to this?  Thanks for any help

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featureFade").animate({opacity:1},400,function(){
        $("#image").delay(300).animate({opacity:1},300,function(){
        $("#title").delay(300).animate({opacity:1},300,function(){
        $("#message, #move").delay(200).animate({opacity:1},300,function(){ 
            $("#move").animate({top: '400px',left: '0px'}, 500,function(){
            $("#nav,#contentContainer,#button,#footer,#topLevelNav").delay(1000).animate({opacity:1},700);
                });
                });
                });
            });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [jQuery Cookie Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) you can do this simply:

```
// check for previous visit
if ($.cookie('hasSeenAnimation') == null){
  // ...
  // play animation
  // ...

  // set cookie to stop next visit
  $.cookie('hasSeenAnimation','true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it on the server side - if the cookie is set, just don't output the code for the animation...