# Rotating an Image only once with a jQuery cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, rotation

On the page load I rotate an image for some time and hide using jQuery. However when I navigate to other pages and come back again to the first one, again it loads that image. How can I make that the rotation will occur only on the first page load?

PS: I know I have to use cookies, but I cannot manage to do it correctly. Can anyone help please?

Here is the code that rotates the image:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var angle = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        angle+=3;
        $("#loading").rotate(angle);
    }, 50);
});
```

I tried to set a defaul cookie as true before the rotation and then change it, but it doesn't work.

```
$.cookie('visited', true);
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if( $.cookie('visited') == true){
            var angle = 0;
            setInterval(function(){
                angle+=3;
                $("#loading").rotate(angle);
            },50);
        $.cookie('visited', false);
    }
});
```

I wonder if this can contradict smth:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Initial loading, after 3 seconds fadeout the loading and show the menu
    $("#loading").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    $(".logo").delay(3500).fadeIn('slow');
    $("footer, nav").delay(4000).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Here I tried to make a kind of animation. The logo, Footer and Nav are hidden with CSS then I fade in those.

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookie('hasSeenAnimation') == null){
        var angle = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            angle+=3;
            $("#loading").rotate(angle);
        },50);

        //Initial Loading, after 3 seconds fadeout the Loading and show Menu
        $("#loading").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".logo").delay(3500).fadeIn('slow');
        $("footer, nav").delay(4000).fadeIn('slow');

        $.cookie('hasSeenAnimation','true');
    }
});
```

But now on the first load it rotates...when I navigate and come back it shows the rotated image, but prevents the rotation (it doesn't rotate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, guys thanks for the help. I just managed to do it, by putting in an `else` statement.

Here is the code in case someone have same issue (notice that this is not the best answer as I'm new to jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookie('hasSeenAnimation') == null){
        var angle = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            angle+=3;
            $("#loading").rotate(angle);
        },50);

        //Initial Loading, after a 3 sec fadeout the loading and show the menu
        $("#loading").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
        $(".logo").delay(3500).fadeIn('slow');
        $("footer, nav").delay(4000).fadeIn('slow');

        $.cookie('hasSeenAnimation', 'true');
    }
    else{
        $("#loading").hide();
        $(".logo").delay(300).fadeIn('slow');
        $("footer, nav").delay(600).fadeIn('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the cookie everytime on page load, instead try

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!$.cookie('visited')) {
        var angle = 0;
        setInterval(function () {
            angle += 3;
            $("#loading").rotate(angle);
        }, 50);
        $.cookie('visited', true);
    }
});
```

PoC: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9qQaL/)

Comment: Thnx for reply:
I tried this, but it prevents even the rotation. Im checking if another action is contradicting with this...

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if( $.cookie('visited') != true){
        var angle = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            angle += 3;
            $("#loading").rotate(angle);
        },50);
        $.cookie('visited', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: nope, same issue...rotates on the first load but when i navigate and come back again it rotates

Comment: just to dbl check, can you verify that you deleted the previous cookie that you set. Clear your cookies, then try.

Comment: look here, same issue it seems with an accepted answer. Though, the OP of that question is using delay and not setInterval . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239020/set-cookie-to-only-play-animation-once-jquery?rq=1

Comment: i checked it, i tried that now on the first load it rotates and when i navigate and come back it prevents the rotation, it just shows the image. I Edit the code. U can check it